# Is Convenient To Use Storyboard In An Application With Many Submenus and Screens?

Tags: xcode, ipad, storyboard

I need to do an application for iPad, and I'm a beginner. 
I've read many books of Objective-C, Applications for iPod and iPad, XCODE.
My application is going to have a main menu (with 15 options/buttons). Every option is going to have a next screen with a submenu/popover with 5-10 options. Every option is going to have maybe a last screen with tables, graphics, etc, or maybe another submenu.
As you can see, I'm going to have a lot of screens. I've read about Storyboard. I've done some examples, and really makes some things very easy, but in these examples, I only have like 5-6 screens, each different from the other...
In my application, I want to make a screen and reuse it in other options, because some screens its going to be very similar, just with different options (like the menus/popup, the tables, the graphics, etc.).
My question is, is convenient to use Storyboard or not?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think storyboards are great (only just started to use them).
I would be tempted to create your app using multiple storyboards.
e.g. MainMenu storyboard and then a separate storyboard for each of the 5-10 options off that screen.

Whilst you could use XIBs for each screen "template", I don't think that will reduce the code you need to write. Yes you can re-use XIBs for multiple screens but you could do the same by having a storyboard with a bunch of orphan viewControllers in.

Your third option is of course to write it all in code; for example write a presentation engine that can create and display view controllers and views at will based upon data stored in a database or plists etc. This is a good option if you plan on creating multiple apps that would benefit from this approach.

Comment: Oh. Thank you very much for your answer. Now I have one question... How can I call a storyboard from another storyboard? Can I have them in the same project or I need to make another project "child"?